# Unable to get jhipster gateway home page

Tags: angular, jhipster, microservices

I am unable to open My JHipster + Angular 2 (Gateway) Application home page with port 8080 (which is given at server port in application-dev.yml)
There is no errors in console.

`index.html` completely loading may be routing is not working fine.

The Same application is running fine on port 9000 (which is provided by yarn)

My problem is if I use 9000 port (Given by yarn) unable to communicate with other micro services applications.

Comment: Yes I started yarn and java (by using yarn:    yarn start,         maven: mvnw). For maven I am unable to get home page, Index file is loading perfectly in source files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Clear cache in your browser
2. Execute command 
       **yarn run webpack:build**

Answer (score 4):

In development:

- run JHipster registry
- on gateway, run both `mvnw` and `yarn start` at same time and then open app in browser at port 9000, all calls to services will be proxied to the java applications transparently: gateway + microservices apps
- run microservices apps with `mvnw`

EDIT:

I looked at your link though I hesitated because it was an archive of 135 MB !!!
Few remarks:

- Next time, please publish source on github rather than packaging node_modules folders
- agreeGatewayV1 uses mysql as dev database which made it difficult for me to run. h2 is much easier to work with especially for a gateway where you are not going to modify the data schema.
- Application-2 does not include a .yo-rc.json file so I couldn't inspect its configuration. Same as your gateway, it uses mysql in dev so I could not test it
- I found 5 java crash reports in your archive, your environment seems very unstable. Maybe you should upgrade your OS and jvm or maybe you don't have enough RAM

So sorry but I can't help you, it would take too much time.

Comment: Thanks @Gaël Marziou, I am doing same but no use.

Comment: OK, then we need more info. Can you share a project on github?

Answer (score 1):

You must add the microservice path to the webpack dev server proxy context.
If your microservice name is `my-microservice` then add a row

```
'/my-microservice',
```

to the file `webpack.dev.js` into section `devServer.proxy.context`.
Note: in gateway, if you are generating the front-end for the entity located in the microservice then the JHipster entity generator already adds this line.

Comment: I have added that row but no change in result

Comment: I looked at link you posted yesterday to other answer. I see that in the project **agreeGatewayV1** in the file **.yo-rc.json** is `"applicationType": "microservice"`.  
In JHipster, gateway is project with `"applicationType": "gateway"`.  
If you generate JHipster gateway project (`"applicationType": "gateway"`) then you can access JHipster microservice project (`"applicationType": "microservice"`) in gateway with webpack dev server if you make change as I suggested.

Comment: I found this answer really helpful as the JHipster documentation just states: "if your gateway is running on localhost:8080, you could point to http://localhost:8080/app1/rest/foos to get the foos resource", and obviously you don't want to hard code the full URL in your services.  However, how does this work for production?  I assume that webpack.dev.js does not take effect in production and there is no equivalent section proxy.context in webpack.prod,js